# How to filter product collection by custom text attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection, custom-attributes

I have a custom attribute in my magento store say "duration". and it has values like "2 Hours", "180 Minutes", "1 day" etc. for display on frontend.

But now I want to filter product collection by this attribute.

For example : I want to filter products with less than "1000 minutes" duration. Collection must return those products which has value in `hours` or `days` (according to hour and day calculation).

Is it possible to filter product collection using this attribute? If yes then How to apply filter on product collection?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to normalize your data, so that the stored value is always in the same unit (e.g. minutes)

To display different values in the frontend, you can write a custom source model:

```
class Your_Module_Model_Source_Duration extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => 120, 'label' => '2 hours'],
            ['value' => 180, 'label' => '180 minutes'],
            ['value' => 1440, 'label' => '1 day'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Then create/update the attribute via install script and specify the source model:

```
'source'        => 'your_module/source_duration',
```